# Is monetary expansion the same as quantitative easing

Tags: monetary-policy, federal-reserve

Is monetary expansion policy the same as quantitative easing (i.e the buying of US treasuries by Federal reserve which injects more USD into the economy)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between Quantitative Easing and regular central bank operations?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/14697/whats-the-difference-between-quantitative-easing-and-regular-central-bank-opera)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not. Monetary expansion is increasing the money supply (through whatever method).

Quantitative easing increases the money supply / injects liquidity, but  also reduces privately hold stocks (and hence can reduce risks from the banks' balance sheets).

Comment: Thanks. What other methods except QE help increase money supply?

Comment: @Victor123 that sounds like a new question to me :)